# Can I configure Visual Studio to create a memory dump when my app crashes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crash, dump

I have a C#/WPF (.net Framework, not core) desktop application that randomly crashes - without warning or any Windows notification. In the Windows Event Viewer the crash is logged with an exception code 0xc0000005, which apparently indicates an unmanaged memory access violation.

This started happening a few weeks ago, in the middle of implementing a new rather complex WPF control. Apart from that the application also has other components with unmanaged code - but to my knowledge these haven't changed in these weeks. And the control that I'm developing works with several threads and VisualTree modifications etc. but is purely WPF/.NET managed code.

And, furthermore: this only happens on my machine, if debugging in Visual Studio. Not on other machines; not, if running the app alone in debug or release mode; not, if I attach another debugger (e.g. ProcDump).

Visual Studio does not appear to be affected at all, it simply stops debugging, but it must have something to do with my app crashing.

I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files?view=vs-2022, but that doesn't help me.

Comment: Did you already tried with enabled "Native" debugging?

Comment: Why don't you want to solve 0xc0000005? If this happens to all the software on your computer, then you should consider updating the driver or there is something wrong with your memory stick. If only Visual Studio is the problem, then please repair Visual Studio and check if there are some suspicious software in your computer that need to be uninstalled

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Open your project/solution in Visual Studio.
2. Go to the "Debug" menu and select "Options."
3. In the "Options" dialog box, navigate to "Debugging" > "Dump Writing."
4. Check the "Create dump file on application crash" option.
5. Specify the path and name of the dump file. You can use the browse button (...) to select a location.
6. Choose the type of dump file you want to generate. The available options are:

   - "Mini dump": This is a small-sized dump file that contains basic information about the crash.
   - "Full dump": This is a larger-sized dump file that contains more detailed information, but it may take longer to generate.

   It's recommended to start with a mini dump file unless you specifically require the additional information provided by a full dump.
7. Click "OK" to save the changes and close the "Options" dialog box.
8. Build and run your application in Debug mode.
9. When your application crashes, Visual Studio will generate a memory dump file at the specified location. The dump file will contain information about the crash, which can be useful for debugging purposes.

Remember to review the generated dump file using debugging tools like Visual Studio's debugger or other specialized tools designed for analyzing memory dumps...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

- Try configuring different architecture types and review any warnings the compiler gives you. Make sure you get over the warnings.
- Visual Studio 2019 and later versions.

Comment: Using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.6.4, I cannot find this option

Comment: You can achieve the same result by configuring it in the project settings. Here's how you can do it:

1. Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer and select "Properties".
2. Navigate to the "Debug" tab.
3. In the "Start Action" section, make sure the "Start external program" option is selected, and specify the path to the executable of your application that you want to debug.
4. Add the following command line arguments to the "Command line arguments" field:
   --collect "DumpHeap;EventLog"
5. Click "Apply" and then "OK" to save the changes.

Comment: Once the crash occurs, go to the "Debug" menu in Visual Studio and select " Save Dump As..." and choose a location to save the memory dump file and provide a name for it.
Save the memory dump file to the specified location.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but apparently we're talking about different VS versions, e.g. my project properties have no "Apply" button. But, more importantly: the suggested command line arguments conflict with my app's evaluation of command line arguments. It seems to be the wrong place for these args..